# Product of two symmetric banded matrices - real eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

Let $A$ and $B$ be real symmetric banded matrices but $AB$ is not symmetric.  Are the eigenvalues of $AB$ real?

A more specific case: let $D$ be a real diagonal matrix, $B$ real symmetric and banded, and $DB$ is not symmetric.  Are the eigenvalues of $DB$ real?

Comment: It is true if at least one of the matrices is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Could you sketch out why that is true?

Comment: If $A$ is positive definite, then $AB$ has the same eigenvalues as $A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2}=A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}=:C$. Since $C$ is symmetric, it has real eigenvalues and so does $AB$. It is still true if $A$ is only semidefinite but the proof is slightly more complicated. AFAIK it can be found in the Horn's and Johnson's Matrix Analysis.

Answer (score 1):

No, 
$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$.

Comment: Thanks for that counter-example. I actually am interested in banded symmetric matrices, so I will edit the original question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by banded, tridiagonal? Are my matrices not banded, if they are just $2\times 2$?

Comment: Yes, tridiagonal, pentadiagonal, etc.

Comment: Actually, banded isn't quite right, because I'm considering also block diagonal, block tridiagonal, etc.  Basically, the matrix will be sparse and non-zero values concentrated near the main diagonal.  The counter-example you gave was anti-diagonal.  I'm not consider such matrices (anti-triadiagonal, and so on).